# Coloring an "inverted" SVG path with CSS

Tags: css, svg

Given this Twitter icon from [materialdesignicons.com](http://materialdesignicons.com):

```html
<svg class="social-icon" style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M17.71,9.33C18.19,8.93 18.75,8.45 19,7.92C18.59,8.13 18.1,8.26 17.56,8.33C18.06,7.97 18.47,7.5 18.68,6.86C18.16,7.14 17.63,7.38 16.97,7.5C15.42,5.63 11.71,7.15 12.37,9.95C9.76,9.79 8.17,8.61 6.85,7.16C6.1,8.38 6.75,10.23 7.64,10.74C7.18,10.71 6.83,10.57 6.5,10.41C6.54,11.95 7.39,12.69 8.58,13.09C8.22,13.16 7.82,13.18 7.44,13.12C7.81,14.19 8.58,14.86 9.9,15C9,15.76 7.34,16.29 6,16.08C7.15,16.81 8.46,17.39 10.28,17.31C14.69,17.11 17.64,13.95 17.71,9.33M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2Z" />
</svg>
```

I've found that I can change the path's fill color by adding a `social-icon` CSS class like this:

```css
.social-icon {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="social-icon" style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M17.71,9.33C18.19,8.93 18.75,8.45 19,7.92C18.59,8.13 18.1,8.26 17.56,8.33C18.06,7.97 18.47,7.5 18.68,6.86C18.16,7.14 17.63,7.38 16.97,7.5C15.42,5.63 11.71,7.15 12.37,9.95C9.76,9.79 8.17,8.61 6.85,7.16C6.1,8.38 6.75,10.23 7.64,10.74C7.18,10.71 6.83,10.57 6.5,10.41C6.54,11.95 7.39,12.69 8.58,13.09C8.22,13.16 7.82,13.18 7.44,13.12C7.81,14.19 8.58,14.86 9.9,15C9,15.76 7.34,16.29 6,16.08C7.15,16.81 8.46,17.39 10.28,17.31C14.69,17.11 17.64,13.95 17.71,9.33M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2Z" />
</svg>
```

Is it possible to "invert" the path coloring so that the Twitter bird itself becomes red instead of the surrounding?

Comment: Try `.social-icon path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with that `<path>`/`<svg>` alone. Basically It is a circle with the bird »cut out«, so all you can color is the circle without the bird.

You need to break the path apart into the background circle and the bird like so:

```html
<svg>
    <path
     d="M 12,2 A 10,10 0 0 1 22,12 10,10 0 0 1 12,22 10,10 0 0 1 2,12 10,10 0 0 1 12,2 Z" />
      <path
     style="fill:#ff0000"
     d="M 17.71,9.33 C 18.19,8.93 18.75,8.45 19,7.92 18.59,8.13 18.1,8.26 17.56,8.33 18.06,7.97 18.47,7.5 18.68,6.86 18.16,7.14 17.63,7.38 16.97,7.5 15.42,5.63 11.71,7.15 12.37,9.95 9.76,9.79 8.17,8.61 6.85,7.16 6.1,8.38 6.75,10.23 7.64,10.74 7.18,10.71 6.83,10.57 6.5,10.41 6.54,11.95 7.39,12.69 8.58,13.09 8.22,13.16 7.82,13.18 7.44,13.12 7.81,14.19 8.58,14.86 9.9,15 9,15.76 7.34,16.29 6,16.08 c 1.15,0.73 2.46,1.31 4.28,1.23 4.41,-0.2 7.36,-3.36 7.43,-7.98" />
</svg>
```